# Protractor can't find angular variable and wait until jasmine default time resulting in failure of tests

Tags: angular, testing, automation, protractor, wait

I am automating some test cases for an angular app. I have the following understanding with Protractor as:

1. In angular apps there is no need of explicit waiting like selenium
       as protractor 90% commands return promises i.e. it means that
       protractor waits by its own.
2. Protractor's function `WaitForAngularEnabled()` is by default `true`.

The problem i am having is that while automating tests for my angular app, when i test my app, protractor waits (and i guess it waits for angular variable) until jasmine default time expires and all test cases fails. When I test my app as Non-Angular (change my protractor conf. settings (**code attached**)), all test cases work finely, but I have to explicitly add waits which results in much flaky tests. It also increases test execution time. Can anyone help me in above mentioned issue. Will be much thankful to you.

```js
onPrepare() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: 'e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json'
    });
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);//Disabled angular here
    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Protractor communicates with Angular, it uses the Angular Testability API, the API returns a variable called is_stable. When this variable is true, it means that your Angular website is stable. Which means that all the promises in your page has been resolved and there are no active processes that the page is waiting for finish.

NOTE: The is_stable flag will give you false if there are still elements that require resolution in your page. This issue usually occurs if your website has any third party integrations that keep running in the background or if there is something in the mobile side that does not load on the webpage. If that is the case, you will need to check if there are any processes pending on your webpage. If there are any processes, you will have to move it outside the Angular's scope. That way Angular will resolve all promises and let Protractor know that it is ready to receive commands.

The other way you can remove explicit waits from your code is by using async await. Async await is simple to use and will explicitly wait for any promise resolution before proceeding froward. Currently the selenium promise manager takes care of all the promises if you are running an older version of protractor, if not, the promise manager is disabled (deprecated) so you will have to manually take care of all the promises.

Comment: Thanks for Your response. uhh The issue is that there are some calls and integrations but even in login page it doesn't proceed where there are no calls and integrations.

Comment: Can you check in your login page if the is_stable flag is true or not, check how long it is taking for that flag to be true. [Here](https://angular.io/api/core/Testability) you can read more about the API.

Comment: Did it work for you? Add a comment on what was the error and how you fixed it as a future reference for others please :)

Comment: i just got that there are several third party integrations that are running in background. and there are numerous calls that is why `is_stable` function doesn't return true

Comment: I got the reason why it marked unaccepted. I used stack exchange in mobile and there i dont know what happened. may be it was the reason. Any ways I accepted it with thanks :)

Comment: I have tried all above the code with `WaitForAngularEnabled(TRUE)` in an angular 9 project and amazingly its working fine. Moreover this angular 9 app does not have any third party integrations

Comment: Yes, that is the magic of using protractor with Angular but you have to make sure of abstracting third party integrations outside Angular scope during design phase.

Comment: I am now working on Angular 6, There `setTimeInterval` is used. So api are called every 2 mins. Protractor waits things to be stable. and Fails. Is there any solution to this?